# What 8-bit encodings use the C1 range for characters? (x80—x9F or 128—159)

Tags: character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

Wikipedia has a listing of the x80—x9F "C1" range under [Latin 1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_unicode_block) for Unicode. This range is also reserved in the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout) codepage.

I'm looking at a file of strings, all of which are within the 7-bit ASCII range except for a few instances of `\x96` where it looks like a dash would be, such as the middle of a street address.

I don't know if other characters in the C1 range might eventually show up in the data, so I'd like to know if there's a correct way to read the file. Are there are any 8-bit encodings which use x80 through x9F for character data instead of terminal control characters?

Comment: Control characters are 0x00 through 0x1F.

Comment: @Jim, I believe those are called the "C0" control characters. There's another range of control characters starting at the high bit (or, at least in some encodings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a large number (potentially an infinite number) of 8-bit encodings that assign graphic characters to some or all bytes in the range 0x80 to 0x9F. Several encodings defined by Microsoft have U+2013 EN DASH “–” at byte position 0x96, and this character could conceivably appear in a street address, especially between numbers.

On the other hand, e.g. MacRoman has the letter “ñ” at position 0x96, and it could well appear within a street name in Spanish, for example.

For a rational analysis of the situation, you should inspect the data as a whole, possibly using a filter that finds all bytes outside the Ascii range 0x00 to 0x7F, look at the contexts in which the characters appear, and try to find technical information about the origin of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. Much better on details.

Comment: There is not an infinite number; there are "only" (17*2^16)^128 possible single-byte supersets of ASCII that map to Unicode code points.

Comment: @dan04, “potentially infinite number” was a strong expression, to make a point, but still literally correct. An encoding need not map code points to Unicode (even though that’s the common way these days); it could map them to whatever characters people can invent.

Answer (score 0):

It's an en dash.  I guess slightly different than a hyphen (0x2D).

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: You're right! The correct answer is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Their codepage includes extended characters for Latin-1 that aren't part of ISO's Latin-1.

Comment: Windows-1252 is one of the possible answers. The data included in the question does not justify any particular conclusion.